# Регулярное выражение, разрезать строку пополам

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите разрезать строку только по первому символу запятой `,`.

> ```
> '"-KlolIDFj_o-sio","{\\"action\\":{\\"text\\":\\"some text\\",\\"url\\":\\"https://example.com?m=true\\"},\\"html\\":\\"\\",\\"time\\":1}"'
> ```

Чтобы получилось:

```
var id = '"-KlolIDFj_o-sio"';
var data = '"{\\"action\\":{\\"text\\":\\"some text\\",\\"url\\":\\"https://example.com?m=true\\"},\\"html\\":\\"\\",\\"time\\":1}"]';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вариант без регулярки подходит? Через нахождение позиции `,` и разделение строки?

```js
var str = '"-KlolIDFj_o-sio","{\\"action\\":{\\"text\\":\\"some text\\",\\"url\\":\\"https://example.com?m=true\\"},\\"html\\":\\"\\",\\"time\\":1}"';
var pos = str.indexOf(',');
var id = str.slice(0, pos);
var data = str.slice(pos + 1);
console.log(id);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, туплю сегодня )

Comment: Можете принять мой ответ как ответ на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно разделить строку с помощью `split()`, первый элемент будет `id`, а остальные можно через `join()` объединить в `data`.

```js
let str = '"-KlolIDFj_o-sio","{\\"action\\":{\\"text\\":\\"some text\\",\\"url\\":\\"https://example.com?m=true\\"},\\"html\\":\\"\\",\\"time\\":1}"';

let array = str.split(',');
let id = array[0];
let data = array.slice(1).join(',');
console.log(id);
console.log(data);
```

Или как вариант, получить первый id через split, а вторую часть получить путем вычитания из всей строки длины id

```js
let str = '"-KlolIDFj_o-sio","{\\"action\\":{\\"text\\":\\"some text\\",\\"url\\":\\"https://example.com?m=true\\"},\\"html\\":\\"\\",\\"time\\":1}"';

let id = str.split(',')[0];
let data = str.slice(id.length + 1);
console.log(id);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про  `indexOf()`.